# SPA in apache using alias

Tags: apache, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm trying to set up apache so it servers an instance of wordpress as the main site and a SPA created with React-Redux in a subpath. I've used [this configuration](https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/apache.html) but it only works when the SPA is the root application.

This is my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin <MY SERVER AMDIN>
        ServerName <MY SERVER NAME>
        ServerAlias <MY SERVER ALIAS>

        Alias /my-sub-site "/var/www/my-sub-app-folder"
        <Directory>
            RewriteEngine on
            # Don't rewrite files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]
            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone done this successfully? When I access the URL at http://myserver/my-sub-site the application doesn't load, in the console I see that the assets (.js,.css,.jpeg,etc) are not being resolved to the subpath /my-sub-site but to the root.

i.e. instead of requesting http://myserver/my-sub-site/vendor.js it's trying to request http://myserver/vendor.js.

Any help will be appreciated.